# Why is my 3d array reversed?

Tags: c, arrays, tetris

I have a 3d array of ints stored in a struct which represents a tetris block:

```
typedef struct
{
  int orientations[4][4][4];
  dimension dimensions[4];
  int i;
  int x;
  int y;
}block;
```

orientations is filled with every possible position for the block and dimension is a struct that provides information for collision checking:

```
typedef struct 
{
int left, right, bottom;
}dimension;
```

each orientation and dimension should be linked by the block's i value. For some reason orientations (but not dimensions) seems to be reversed. Does anybody know why this is?

here is how I assign values to dimensions:

```
block* shape = malloc(sizeof(block));
shape->dimensions[0].left = 0;
shape->dimensions[0].right = 3;
shape->dimensions[0].bottom = 1;
shape->dimensions[1].left = 2;
shape->dimensions[1].right = 2;
shape->dimensions[1].bottom = 3;
shape->dimensions[2].left = 0;
shape->dimensions[2].right = 3;
shape->dimensions[2].bottom = 2;
shape->dimensions[3].left = 1;
shape->dimensions[3].right = 1;
shape->dimensions[3].bottom = 3;
```

and orientations:

```
int first[4][4] = {{0,0,0,0}, {2,2,2,2}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}};
int second[4][4] = {{0,0,2,0},{0,0,2,0},{0,0,2,0},{0,0,2,0}};
int third[4][4] = {{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{2,2,2,2},{0,0,0,0}};
int fourth[4][4] = {{0,2,0,0},{0,2,0,0},{0,2,0,0},{0,2,0,0}};
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    shape->orientations[0][i][j] = first[i][j];
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    shape->orientations[1][i][j] = second[i][j];
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    shape->orientations[2][i][j] = third[i][j];
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    shape->orientations[3][i][j] = fourth[i][j];
  }
}
```

here is how I'm accessing the array:

```
shape->orientations[current->i][i][j]
```

when I attempt to access shape->orientations[3] it returns the values I set to shape->orientations[0] earlier. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really hard to follow your code snippets and question. For example, there is no `current` in your code snippet at all yet you reference it in your question. I suggest you reformat your question with a single [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your array is indexed `[orientation][row][column]`, but you are interpreting it as `[orientation][x][y]` when you should be interpreting it as `[orientation][y][x]`. So you are getting a pattern with the x and y swapped, which appears as if it has been rotated to a different orientation (actually it's equivalent to a rotation and a flip).

Comment: Awesome thank you, I was so focused on figuring out how an array magically reversed itself I didn't even consider that I had made a mistake.